# How to give same colour for each bar in stacked chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How to give same colour in Google Visualization Stacked Bar Charts for  different bar.
I also try to find Google but I not found any useful solution.I want like this..please Check this link:  [Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjB4m.jpg)

Comment: Use "style" role columns to control color; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21264811/613559).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try as suggested in this answer: [Google Charts - Change individual bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592776/google-charts-change-individual-bar-color)

```
function drawVisualization() {
// Create and populate the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'SalesMax');

        data.addRows(4);
        data.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 0);

        data.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
        data.setValue(1, 1, 1170);
        data.setValue(1, 2, 0);

/* NEED TO MAKE THIS BAR RED? */
        data.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
        data.setValue(2, 1, 0);
        data.setValue(2, 2, 1400);

        data.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
        data.setValue(3, 1, 1030);
        data.setValue(3, 2, 0);


        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart.draw(data, {isStacked: true, width: 400, height: 240, title: 'Company Performance',
                          vAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
                          series: [{color: 'blue', visibleInLegend: true}, {color: 'red', visibleInLegend: false}]
                         });
}
```

Comment: I try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592776/google-charts-change-individual-bar-color....but I look for same colour  for one bar in stacked form for different bar dark colour on bottom and same bright colour on top..